# regular expression with or condition in middle of expression

Tags: regex

I'm having a problem with an `|` expression in the middle of my regular expression validator in asp.net. I want a user to be able to enter a string like this

```
AB/123/123/12
AB/12/123/12
```

Here is my regular expression

```
        AB[\/]^\d{3}|\d{2}$[\/]\d{3}[\/]\d{2}
```

I've tested this part seperately

```
       ^\d{3}|\d{2}$
```

and it works but when it's in the middle of the first regular expression it doesn't seem to. It's probably something small i'm missing but I can't see it. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What regex flavor? What tool? The syntax depends on what you're using. Also, please explain what your regex is supposed to be doing. Since it's not actually doing it, we have no idea what your objective is.

Comment: I'm using an asp.net regular expression validator on a text box, i'll edit the original post to say that.

Comment: OK, also explain what you're supposed to be matching. Your second regex matches only the beginning of the string, is that what you want? Please describe what conditions your regex needs to fulfill. What's a good string and what's a bad string?

Comment: It's probably the end of line anchor `$` - you have it in the middle of the expression so if anything matches the rest will be ignored

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter AB/ followed by either two or 3 digits, followed by another dash, 3 digits, dash, 2 digits.

So AB/12/456/11 or AB/123/456/11

Answer (score 3):

Putting the starting and ending anchors (`^` and `$`) anywhere other than a position where they could start or end the string means that the regular expression is bound to fail to match. Instead, you could use parentheses to confine what the or statement is relevant to:

```
AB[\/](\d{3}|\d{2})[\/]\d{3}[\/]\d{2}
```

But, it's better to just condense it as far as possible.

```
AB\/\d{2,3}\/\d{3}\/\d{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `^AB\/(\d{3}|\d{2})\/\d{3}\/\d{2}$`